# Declare Variable in VBA

Tags: vba, variables

I am beginner in vba, I can’t understand the below code even I searched a lot about it and didn’t find any thing.
What is the meaning of put (x) and declare it with different type?

```
    Const x = 25 
    Dim y(x) As Double
    Dim z(x) As Boolean
```

Any hlep will be appreciation

Comment: The x in brackets is the size if the array. Is that what you're after or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes it the size. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is declaring an array with the same amount of values as x as the specified type

```
Const x = 25 
    Dim y(x) As Double = array of 25 double
    Dim z(x) As Boolean = array of 25 booleans
```

Comment: usually unless option base is set to 1 it's actually 26 (0 to 25)

Answer (score 3):

`y` and `z` are arrays, each with 25 elements.

`y` is an array of 25 `Double`s and `z` is an array of 25 `Boolean`s.

There are any number of VBA tutorials that will teach you about arrays; here's one example: [Array in Excel VBA](http://www.vbtutor.net/VBA/vba_chp21.htm)